# allrunes changes default font slightly

Tags: fonts, symbols, renewcommand

I am trying to use a specific rune as a symbol in a document. I'm able to use the `allrunes` package to do so. The `allrunes` documentation specifically says that it does not change the default font of the main text. However, when the document is compiled *on certain computers*, the main text font changes ever so slightly.

I have tried changing the command where we define the symbol so that it only uses the allrunes font locally in the following way:

`\newcommand{\hagal}{{\allrunes{\large{\textarm{\textlf{h}}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!{\raisebox{0.5\depth}{\phantom|$^{\bullet}_{\pm}$}}}}`

but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

A minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{allrunes}

\newcommand{\hagal}{{\large{\textarm{\textlf{h}}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!{\raisebox{0.5\depth}{\phantom|$^{\bullet}_{\pm}$}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Bad Font}
\hagal
\end{document}
```

---

**SUPPLEMENT** (S Segletes)

Reducing the MWE to be `allrunes` free:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage{allrunes}

\newcommand{\hagal}{{\large{\textarm{\textlf{h}}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!{\raisebox{0.5\depth}{\phantom|$^{\bullet}_{\pm}$}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Bad Font}
%\hagal
\end{document}
```

gives this font:

[image]

Loading `allrunes`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{allrunes}

\newcommand{\hagal}{{\large{\textarm{\textlf{h}}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!{\raisebox{0.5\depth}{\phantom|$^{\bullet}_{\pm}$}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Bad Font}
%\hagal
\end{document}
```

produces one error: `command \swdefault already defined`, and produces this output:

[image]

A diff of the two log files is as follows:

```
1c1
< This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.12)  17 JAN 2022 16:43
---
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.12)  17 JAN 2022 16:46
83a84,136
> (C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/allrunes\allrunes.
> sty
> Package: allrunes 2004/01/06 v2.1 allrunes package.
> 
> (C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
> Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
> )
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \mdseries on input line 43.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \bfseries on input line 55.
> 
> 
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \swdefault already defined.
>                Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
> 
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>                                                   
> l.94 \newcommand{\swdefault}{t}
>                                 % straight, low twigs
> ? 
> (C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/allrunes\arc.fd
> Now handling font encoding LRC ...
> ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LRC
> )
> (C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/allrunes\ara.fd
> Now handling font encoding LRA ...
> ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LRA
> )
> (C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/allrunes\arn.fd
> Now handling font encoding LRN ...
> ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LRN
> LaTeX Info: Composite with undeclared \. in encoding LRN on input line 74.
> LaTeX Info: Composite with undeclared \" in encoding LRN on input line 78.
> )
> (C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/allrunes\art.fd
> Now handling font encoding LRT ...
> ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LRT
> )
> (C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/allrunes\arl.fd
> Now handling font encoding LRL ...
> ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LRL
> )
> (C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/allrunes\arm.fd
> Now handling font encoding LRM ...
> ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LRM
> LaTeX Info: Composite with undeclared \. in encoding LRM on input line 122.
> LaTeX Info: Composite with undeclared \' in encoding LRM on input line 123.
> LaTeX Info: Composite with undeclared \^ in encoding LRM on input line 125.
> LaTeX Info: Composite with undeclared \~ in encoding LRM on input line 127.
> LaTeX Info: Composite with undeclared \= in encoding LRM on input line 128.
> LaTeX Info: Composite with undeclared \" in encoding LRM on input line 132.
> ))
105a159,170
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LRC/fruc/m/n on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LRA/frua/m/n on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LRN/frun/m/n on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LRT/frut/m/n on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LRL/frul/m/n on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LRM/frum/m/n on input line 8.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
171,175c236,240
<  1759 strings out of 478927
<  27379 string characters out of 2850131
<  325145 words of memory out of 3000000
<  19647 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
<  404334 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
---
>  3348 strings out of 478927
>  60277 string characters out of 2850131
>  331147 words of memory out of 3000000
>  21205 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
>  404337 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
177c242
<  72i,5n,80p,228b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
---
>  72i,5n,80p,228b,111s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
179,181c244,246
< ic/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Users/Steven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fo
< nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
< Output written on junk.pdf (1 page, 19101 bytes).
---
> ic/amsfonts/cm/cmb10.pfb><C:/Users/Steven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fon
> ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
> Output written on junk.pdf (1 page, 19123 bytes).
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: Hi, just updated it with a minimal working example! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, I see no bad font with this code. Note that that the definition of `\hagal` you are giving in the MWE is not the same one as in the snippet (where you have an extra `\allrunes`, which as far as I can see is not defined). Please explain what code is giving you problems and what output you get.

Comment: I agree that if you run it you probably won't see that there's any bad font. It's an *extremely subtle* change from the usual default font. The letters are slightly narrower and closer together. Furthermore, it only happens when the code is compiled on some computers, but not others.

In the snippet above the MWE I am showing a fix I tried, which was to only call the \allrunes font locally, instead of using \usepackage{allrunes} in the preamble. I did this because I thought if I only used the font when I needed it, it wouldn't change the font of the main text.

Comment: The package does, however, redefine `\bfseries`, which is what would be used in the affected section header font.

Comment: Just to be sure: When you say that it changes the font on "certain computers" you mean that, on those computers, the font looks different with and without the package, right? Not just that it looks different than on other computers? Could you add screenshots of both versions to your question and add some information on the setup of the offending computers (OS, TeX distribution and version, `allrunes` package version)?

Comment: @schtandard I mean that _with_ the `allrunes` package, section headings look different when compiled on different computers. Without `allrunes`, they look exactly the same no matter which computer you compile it on (it's the classic Computer Modern font). The updated code that was added by Steven perfectly shows the issue.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes oh, interesting! Is there a way around that? Can I delete that redefinition in the package by hand or anything?

Comment: By the way---all I really need is to be able to use the symbol ᚼ in the document. Maybe there is an easier way to use this one symbol than loading the entire `allrunes` package?

Comment: Okay I solved it in a very slipshod way---I just defined a new symbol using an uploaded png version of the symbol I need. Not the most elegant, but at least now I don't have to use the `allrunes` package.

Comment: You could post an answer to your own question to that effect.  If no one else provides a better one in time, you could "accept" your own answer.

Comment: I had this same issue and will do the same thing... I also just needed one specific rune.